# Ionic 3 - all if are activated at the same time (JS)

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, button, ionic-framework

I have a little problem and i can't find the solution,

i have this little fonction here:

```
Clicked(){
       for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(i)) {
            alert(i)
          }
        }
}
```

There 6 buttons and what i'm trying to do is when I click a button the `alert()` fonction will launch. The problem is that when I run the program, it shows the 6 alerts in a row. 
I tried to write different way but same issue.

```
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(1)) {
  alert(1)
}
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(2)) {
  alert(2)
}
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(3)) {
  alert(3)
}
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(4)) {
  alert(4)
}
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(5)) {
  alert(5)
}
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(6)) {
  alert(6)
}
```

or

```
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(1)) {
  alert(1)
}
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(2)) {
  alert(2)
}
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(3)) {
  alert(3)
}
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(4)) {
  alert(4)
}
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(5)) {
  alert(5)
}
if (this.ShareProvider.ValueFonction(6)) {
  alert(6)
}
```

Thanks for you attention

Answer (score 0):

you can do that of a lot of ways, i suggest you to create an array on the Ts template, then call them in an ngFor in Html, with a (click) function to call alert with current index. For example:

**In the TS Template:**

declare an array var with the lenght at the top of class, for example:

```
array= new Array(5);
```

a function to alert the index:

```
clicked(i){
     alert(i);
}
```

*and in the html template:*

```
  <div *ngFor="let a of array; let i = index">
    <button (click)="alert(i)> Click me </button>
  </div>
```

Thats will show an alert based on the element index